# Passar parâmetros pela url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mvc, razor

Estou tentando passar um parâmetro da minha view para minha controller pela url e não estou conseguindo, como podem ver no código abaixo estou usando viewbag, não sei se é um erro na rota ou em algo mais, se quiserem qualquer outra parte do código é só pedir:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Consultar", "Contrato", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "oForm" }))
{
    <input name="pIdContrato" type="text" maxlength="200" id="pIdContrato" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Id do Contrato" value="@ViewBag.IdContrato">
}

 @Html.ActionLink("Consultar", "Consultar", "Contrato", new { id = @ViewBag.IdContrato}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
```

Segue a controller:

```
using Sistema.Modelo;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sistema.Models;
using Sistema.Web.Mapeamento;
using Sistema.Repositorio;

namespace Sistema.Controllers
{
    public class ContratoController : Controller
    {

        private readonly SistemaJoaoContext _context = new SistemaContext();
        public ActionResult Contrato()
        {
            return View("Contrato");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Consultar(int id)
        {
            var _ContratoRepositorio = new ContratoRepositorio();
            ViewBag.pIdContrato = id;

            var _Contrato = await _ContratoRepositorio.buscarContrato(id);

            var _ContratoView = MapperFacade.MapperConfiguration.Map<ContratoView>(_Contrato);

            //var _ContratoView = MapperFacade.MapperConfiguration.Map<ContratoView>(await _ContratoRepositorio.buscarContrato(id));

            return View("Consultar", _ContratoView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está o TceController?

Comment: Adicionei o código da controller à pergunta...

Comment: A view mostrada acima é a `~/Views/Tce/Consultar.cshtml`?

Answer (score 4):

No controller, a linha está assim:

```
ViewBag.pIdTce = id;
```

E na view,

```
new { id = @ViewBag.IdTce }
```

Faltou o *p*!

Comment: Mesmo assim o problema persiste.

Comment: A view mostrada acima é a `~/Views/Tce/Consultar.cshtml`?

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que você precisar pegar alguma coisa que vem pela rota, é necessário especificar no `[HttpGet]`. Faça o seguinte no decorator do método:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Consultar(int id)
```